# Odd behavior in $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following `$scope.watch` function:

```
$scope.logChecked = []; 
$scope.selectAll = false;
$scope.$watch('selectAll', function(selectAll) {
       console.log($scope.logChecked.length, $scope.logChecked, selectAll);
});
```

The `console.log()` output correctly enumerates `$scope.logChecked` while `$scope.logChecked.length` shows `0`

> 0 [pf2n1448: false, cc7a1340: false, cc7a1328:
>   false, pf2n1424: false, if2n1328: false…] true

I am modifying logsChecked with the following checkbox:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="logChecked[log.batchId]"/></td>
```

What's going on here?

Comment: please show how you are modifying `logsChecked`

Comment: you haven't actually resized the array.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why the downvote. Thanks to @DanielA.White, I realized that I needed to expound a bit on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `logChecked` is an array with nothing inside (hence `length` is `0`), but you attached properties to it (arrays are still objects).

```js
var foo = [];

foo.bar = 'baz';

document.write(foo.length); // 0

document.write(foo.bar); // "baz"
```

The part that isn't obvious is that `log.batchId` isn't numeric. Thus `logChecked[log.batchId]` attaches that value as a property of `logChecked`, but not inside the array.

Your problem could be solved by making `logChecked` an object (`{}`) instead. To get the number of things in that object, use `Object.keys($scope.logChecked).length`